# Sandboxed solution -get SharePoint lists programmatically

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution

I am using the below code for retrieving all sharepoint lists from a site.

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername:port");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPListCollection SPlists = web.Lists;
foreach (SPList list in SPlists)
  {
    // do something
  }
```

But while deploying it shows the error

> "Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's
>   Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error
>   has occurred."

Any ideas how can we get sharepoint lists and list items from a a site in sandboxed solution?

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% suer, but I think that SPSite constructor is not allowed in sandboxed mode, so You have to obtain your SPSite instance differently.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a very generic sandbox error. This error can be thrown due to a variety of reasons by the SharePoint Sandbox.

Can you debug with Visual Studio? I would suggest you use some kind of logging mechanism if you cannot debug your solution directly with VS. Try the following code:

```
try
{
    using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername:port"))
    {
        using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPListCollection SPlists = web.Lists;
            foreach (SPList list in SPlists)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div>"+ ex.Message() +"</div>"));
}
```

Comment: while debugging it does not throw any error! I will get the lists successfully, But the error is shown when in the sharepoint page

Comment: Then I guess this has something to do with the Environment. Make sure all the sandbox processes and services are running properly.

Comment: They are running....one thing i found that if i use SPContext.Current.Web.Lists then the code will not throw exception. But i need to find a way other than this. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you find what exactly happens using SharePoint Log Viewer?

http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the CURRENT context inside sandboxed code, ergo a correction to this code would be

```
SPListCollection SPlists = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists;
foreach (SPList list in SPlists)
  {
    // do something
  }
```